# Suggestions for optimizing this java code with Math functions

Tags: java

I have the following java code. I am trying to optimize the function

```
        while(pStart < audio.length) {

        int pEnd = Math.round(pStart + winSize*Fs);

        int windowEnd = Math.min(pEnd, audio.length);
        double[] window = new double[fftSize*2];

        for(int i = pStart; i < windowEnd; i++) {
            window[(i-pStart)*2] = audio[i];
        }

        fft.complexForward(window);

        double fftVal;
        for(int i = 0; i < fftSize/2; i++) {

            fftVal = Math.sqrt((window[i*2] * window[i*2])  + (window[i*2+1] * window[i*2+1] ));

            powerAll[i][index] = 20 * Math.log10(
                    Math.abs(fftVal) / (windowEnd - pStart));
        }
        index++;


        pStart = pStart + windowSlide;


    }
```

Timing as per trace files:

Total 2500 ms
fft ~500 ms
self ~900 ms
second for loop ~900 ms

So, my focus is to optimize the second for loop as for now. I cannot change the fft function.

On the same issue, I am not sure, why the tracer reports "self" to be 900 ms.

Comment: If you state what you are trying to do then proposing solution can be easy!

Comment: and what does bulky of time means?. Unless fftVal is really big number,it should not be that way, unless meaning of bulky have changed!

Comment: isn't `window[i*2] * window[i*2]` the same as to do : `Math.pow(window[i*2], 2)` ?

Comment: @Eldarion It is the same functionally, but possibly much faster.

Comment: Do you have the FFT results preprocessed and not figuring into the performance you are measuring? Because I find it very hard to believe that your posted code can take the same order of time as the FFT processing itself.

Comment: Does "fft" in your code stand for "fast Fourier transform"? In that case, if you are trying to create a fast enough FFT, have you googled for something like "fastest FFT Java implementation"?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy OP's code is not the FFT transform; it's about processing the outcome of FFT.

Comment: @Stefano This code is being run in a bigger for loop, and hence forms a big chunk of processing.

Comment: @Himz where is that loop in the post? Is it not that you are trying to optimize code and culprit might well be that loop?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Actually, I am using a library which is implementing bluestein fft algo. I cannot change the library(Project constraints). 
Due to loops, this code actually ending up taking more time that fft(order of 500 ms), and the above takes about(900 ms)

Comment: You are not showing the loops, maybe there's a clever trick to reduce the amout of looping? Just the part you posted doesn't look like a promising target for further optimization.

Comment: @Stefano The above code, is inside a while loop. The total time by while loop is 2400 ms. In while loop i do fft, then processing via above loop. fft takes 500 ms, and above loop takes 900 ms.
Rest ~900 ms goes to other parts of while loop(which I am trying to optimize too.)

Comment: @Stefano I edited the post to contain the loop

Comment: @Himz it seems like you are doing wave/audio processing. The first thing I would ask is, do you need to process everything or just a part at a time? If the latter is valid I would process needed chunk at a time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code can be simplified by applying math properties of log function.

Consider the following function extracted from the original code:

```
double original( double[] window, int i, int windowEnd, int pStart ) {
    double fftVal = Math.sqrt(
            ( window[ i * 2 ] * window[ i * 2 ] )
                    + ( window[ i * 2 + 1 ] * window[ i * 2 + 1 ] )
    );
    return 20 * Math.log10(
            Math.abs( fftVal ) / ( windowEnd - pStart ) );
}
```

Basically, we have the following function in the pseudo-code:

```
x = sqrt(w[2i]^2 + w[2i+1]^2)
return 20 * log( abs(x) / ( windowEnd - pStart ) )
```

- abs is not required, because the value of the sqrt() is non-negative.
- log(X/Y) == log(X) - log(Y)
- log(sqrt(X)) = 0.5 log(X)
- log(windowEnd - pStart) can be precalculated and cashed

The simplified variant with explanations of each step:

```
double variant( double[] window, int i, int windowEnd, int pStart ) {

    // w[2i]^2 + w[2i+1]^2
    double temp1 = window[ i * 2 ] * window[ i * 2 ]
            + window[ i * 2 + 1 ] * window[ i * 2 + 1 ];

    // apply log(sqrt(X)) == log(X^0.5) == 0.5 log(X)
    double temp2 = 0.5 * Math.log10( temp1 );

    // calculate the value of Math.log10( windowEnd - pStart )
    // (and cache it outside of the function) 
    double tempConst3 = Math.log10( windowEnd - pStart );

    // apply log(X/Y) == log(X) - log(Y)
    double temp4 = temp2 - tempConst3;

    return 20 * temp4;
}
```

Comment: Though, novel approach, but with this, I am ending up using two Math.log10 calls - which are expensive. I tested it, and my runtime actually increased.
I have removed the abs function.

Comment: I have mentioned twice that you can cache the Math.log10( windowEnd - pStart ) outside of that function and outside of your inner loop. When done properly, you inner loop will have a single Math.log10 call and zero divisions.

Comment: +1: I measured `16.8 ns` for (an equivalent of) OP's code and `14.9 ns` for your code. It's a meager 12% improvement, but still...

Comment: This code helped me optimize to the scale of 20%. That was great saving. I ended up doing similar things at many places in the big project and the total optimization i achieved was 30-40%(including some other optimizations too!) . Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is an easy target for parallelization. You could either:

1. do it by hand, calculating the subarray indices to pass to each thread;
2. use `ForkJoin` which handles many aspects for you;
3. use Java 8 which has just been released and write this as a `parallelStream` processing task.

My choice would certainly be number 3, if nothing else then for the fun of it.

I took some time to measure your code on my setup, using jmh. It takes 14 nanoseconds per entry of the `window` array. Given the amount of calculation done I think this is already a great result and couldn't be improved by any significant margin.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at java8. Will give option 3 a try. 
I edited the post, to include complete code and timings

Answer (score 0):

The simple optimizations that you can do is to store the value of `window[i*2]` and `window[i*2+1]` in a variable and use them in the `sqrt()` method which will reduce the number of array accesses.

Other than that, if you could say what you are trying to do, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: The JIT will handle the reduced array access anyway.